# Tableview cell WKWebview height as per content in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, wkwebview

i am using WKWebView in table cell and i need to figure out WKWebView content height to manage the table view height but i am able to achieve proper height. below is my effort

```
// calling delegate on cell like this 
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TourDetailsOverviewCell", for: indexPath) as! TourDetailsOverviewCell
  cell.tourOverviewDescriptionWebView.navigationDelegate = self
  cell.tourOverviewDescriptionWebView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
  cell.tourOverviewDescriptionWebView.loadHTMLString(self.tourDetails?.tourDetail?.tourOverview?.description ?? "", baseURL: nil)       
  return cell


 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    if (self.webViewHeight != 0.0) {
          //we already know height, no need to reload cell
        return
    }

    webView.frame.size.height = 0.0
    if webView.isLoading == false {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
            if complete != nil {
                let height = webView.scrollView.contentSize
                print("height of webView is: \(height)")
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                    //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                        self.webViewHeight = height as! CGFloat
                    print("height of webView is: \(self.webViewHeight)")
                    //self.webViewHeight = height as! CGFloat
                    //self.containerHeight.constant = height as! CGFloat
                })
            }
        })
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
  }
```

Any reference will be also appreciated. sorry for my bad english

Comment: what's the problem though? is the height not retrieved from the javascript? or is it that the height is retrieved but it's not translating to the cell?

Comment: this is also rough since the delay waiting for the value of size to return from the java script injection. you'll probably want to cache these values so you don't have to recheck height every time you reload table view. also, i'd say that your         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { is in the wrong place, this is a bad way to do this, you should be using chained promises to chain together size extraction with the last promise being reload rows.

Comment: @Loxx Height is retrieved but its very long than the content

Comment: then you have to create a function that takes the width and size of the webview and normalize that to a maximum pre-defined size that doesn't exceed the bounds of the cell. so you make that resizing function to then fit into the cell just right.